# Can a MWS token for Amazon Germany be used on Amazon UK?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I would like to use MWS token from Amazon Germany on Amazon UK. Both accounts are set up separately. (They are not linked)

We've tried making calls but receiving an error message, so we aren't sure if it's an error or prevented by Amazon.

Can a MWS token for Amazon Germany be used on an independent Amazon UK account?

Answer (score 0):

No, you need to set up developer credentials for every marketplace that you want communicate with via the MWS API's. This is true regardless of whether or not the marketplaces are linked.